Does changing your Mac name affect your SSH key?
I was setting up new SSH keys on my Mac for usage on BitBucket and GitHub. I had not named my Mac yet so it had the default name of <my name's> MacBook Pro.
When I was pasting the ssh key in bitbucket I saw right at the end it said <myname>@<mynames>MacBookpro.local.
So I was wondering. If I rename my Mac from <my name's> MacBook Pro to Lion, what will happen to my SSH key? Will it still work as expected?
I had created an SSH config file to specify which SSH key to use for different accounts (personal and company) on BitBucket and GitHub.

No, it doesn’t affect anything at all.
Go ahead and change it; it will still work.

“When I was pasting the ssh key in bitbucket I saw right at the end it said <myname>@<mynames>MacBookpro.local.
So I was wondering. If I rename my Mac from <my name's> MacBook Pro to Lion, what will happen to my SSH key? Will it still work as expected?”

No, it doesn’t affect anything. Because the preceding text is a hash/gobbledygook, that name is appended to the very end of the key for it to be human readable. It is effectively an inline comment in the key itself; it defaults to user@hostname but it can be anything.
Read more about it here in this Server Fault answer. And here in the official ssh-keygen man page:

“For RSA1 keys, there is also a comment field in the key file that is only for convenience to the user to help identify the key. The comment can tell what the key is for, or whatever is useful. The comment is initialized to ''user@host'' when the key is created, but can be changed using the -c option.”

Go ahead and change it to steve@apple.com or biden@whitehouse.gov and as long as the key/hash/gobbledygook is the same, the key will work.

for extra fun, practically you can use the same public/private key across different systems. I have my private key on my laptop and desktop, and the ubuntu machines I build across my homelab pull these in during setup from github.

essentially you can run those keys on entirely different systems, and the key would work, its not tied into the hostnames at all.
